# Why does my program give a segmentation fault every so often with odd integers, but works fine with any even integers?

Tags: c, malloc, function-pointers

My program is supposed to take an integer as an array length value, then create the array of random numbers from 1 to 1000000 of that length. Then using sieve of Eratosthenes it has to find the largest prime factor of every number from the array of random numbers. Then it should print out all of the elements of the array of random numbers with their biggest prime factor.

The problem now is that it seems to work just fine with any even integers of any size, but gives a segmentation error every once in a while with odd numbers. I suppose that something is incorrect in the *findMaxPrimeFactor function, but have no idea what exactly.

I am compiling it in Linux.

Function main

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include"ArrayOfRandom.h"
#include"MaxPrimeFactor.h"
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
int arrayLength = 0;
if (argc < 3) { // checking if there are enough arguments in the input
        for (int j = 0; j < argv[1][j]; j++) { // checking every character
            if (argv[1][j] >= 48 && argv[1][j] <= 57) {   // ASCII codes from 48 to 57 represent characters from '0' to '9' respectively 
                arrayLength = atoi(argv[1]); // atoi function converts the command line arguments into integers. mod 10 is used to finally get the arrayLength value 
            } else {
                printf("The input should be of an integer value.\n"); // once the invalid character is found, the error message is printed
                exit(0); // exiting the program
                }

        }
} else {
    printf("Please input just 1 value\n"); // if the user tries to put values with spaces, print error message
    exit(0);  // exit the program
}
int *array = arrayOfRandom(arrayLength);// calling of the function that creates the array of random integers

for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; ++i)
{
    printf("Largest prime factor of %d is %d", *(array + i), findMaxPrimeFactor(*(array + i)));
    printf("\n");
}

return 0;
```

}

Function that is supposed to create an array of random numbers in the range of 1000000. It takes arrayLength as a parameter from the main function

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include"ArrayOfRandom.h"
int *arrayOfRandom(int arrayLength) {
srand(time(NULL)); // seed generator for pseudo-random numbers
int *array = NULL;
array = (int*)malloc(arrayLength * sizeof(*array)); 
if (array == NULL) {
    printf("ERROR: memory allocation did not succeed\n");
} else {
    int i; // loop counter
    int range = 1000000;
    for (i = 0; i <= arrayLength; i++) {
        *(array + i) = rand() % range + 1; // range of random integers from 1 to 1000000
    }
}
return (void *)array;
free(array); // Freeing the reserved memory for the array
```

}

Function that is supposed to implement sieve of Eratosthenes(I think the problem is here somewhere). I used the pseudocode from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include"MaxPrimeFactor.h"
int *findMaxPrimeFactor(int number) { 
int *arrayOfBoolean = NULL;
int maxFactor = 0;
arrayOfBoolean = malloc(number * sizeof(*arrayOfBoolean)); /* Length of the boolean array is supposed to be the same as the value of each number from the array of random numbers(every time it is called)*/
if (arrayOfBoolean == NULL) {
    printf("ERROR: memory allocation did not succeed\n");
}
else {
    int i = 0, j = 0; // loop counters
    for (i = 2; i < number; i++) { // initializing the array elements to true
        *(arrayOfBoolean + i) = 1;
    }

    for (i = 2; i*i < number; i++) { // Implementation of the Sieve
        if (*(arrayOfBoolean + i) == 1) {
            for (j = i * i; j < number; j += i) {
                *(arrayOfBoolean + j) = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Finding the largest prime factor   */
    for (i = 2; i <= number; i++) { 
        if ((*(arrayOfBoolean + i) == 1) && (number%i == 0) && (maxFactor < i)) {
            maxFactor = i;
        }
        else if(maxFactor == 0){
            maxFactor = number;
        }
        }
}
return (void *)maxFactor;
free(arrayOfBoolean);
```

}

Headers(Supposed to be separate .h files MaxPrimeFactor.h and ArrayOfRandom.h)

```
int *arrayOfRandom(int arrayLength);
int *findMaxPrimeFactor(int number);
```

Comment: Please note you are leaking memory (you should call free() **before** return). Also, the code you pasted doesn't compile fine: return (void *)array; should just be just return array; ... can you please ensure the example you posted compiles fine?

Comment: At `}
return (void *)array;
free(array);
}` the `free()` is dead code; the `return` means the `free()` is never executed.  Ditto for `}
return (void *)maxFactor;
free(arrayOfBoolean);
}`

Comment: `int j = 0; j < argv[1][j]; j++` is suspicious.  I'd expect `int j = 0; argv[1][j]; j++`.  Many other issues.

Comment: Among the dozens of issues, this is probably the one that causes the crashes: `i <= arrayLength`

Comment: Note: When `number` is near `INT_MAX`, then `i*i < number` is a problem as `i*i` may overflow `int` math.  `i < number/i` does not have this problem - yet a bit slower.

Comment: `int *findMaxPrimeFactor`  --> Why does code return a pointer and not an `int`?

Comment: Thank you, fixed "return (void *) array" to "return array". Although putting "return"  before freeing the memory only made it worse. Now it just prints out "Largest prime factor of 0 is 0"

Comment: Fixed "i <= arrayLength" to "i < arrayLength", now it works much better, thanks, Art!

Comment: none of the proposed fixes are in the posted code.  Please post a 'edit' to append the corrected code.  (don't change the original code

Comment: in general, the call to `srand()` should be performed only once, usually very early in the `main()` function.

Comment: regarding: `srand(time(NULL));`  This will not cleanly compile, because the function: `srand()` is expecting a `unsigned int` parameter.

Comment: regarding: `array = (int*)malloc(arrayLength * sizeof(*array));`  The returned type all of the heap allocation functions `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`  is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.

Comment: regarding: `printf("ERROR: memory allocation did not succeed\n");`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  And when the error is from a C library function, the text reason the system thinks the error occurred should also be output.  Strongly suggest using `perror()` as that will output your text and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Comment: Please post the actual contents of the two 'home grown'  header files.  And since the variables: `arraylength` and `number` are not yet defined, the result is trash

Comment: regarding: `*(arrayOfBoolean + i) `  this kind of notation is difficult to read.  Suggest: `arrayOfBoolean[  i ]`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) separate code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line  3)  consistently indent the code.  Indent after EVERY opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'. Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Comment: the function: `int *findMaxPrimeFactor( int number )` is called multiple times in a loop.  However, each pass through the function is performing a new call to `malloc`.  BUT the allocated memory is not being passed to `free()`  Because after the `return` statement is executed, nothing else in that function will executed.  Strongly suggest placing the call to `free()` before the `return` statement.

Comment: regarding: `arrayOfBoolean = malloc(number * sizeof(*arrayOfBoolean));`  all the parameter bits passed to `malloc()` need to be of type: `size_t`  However, `number` is of type `int`  so the compiler will output a warning message about the conversion to `size_t` may fail.

Comment: Regarding: `for (i = 2; i*i < number; i++)`  this has a 'possible' logic problem in the ordering of the calculations.  Suggest using parens to force the correct ordering.  I.E. for (i = 2; (i*i) < number; i++)

Comment: in function: `findMaxPrimeFactor()`  the code that loops through the array `arrayOfBoolean` and set all multiples of the current value `i` to 0  has to do this again for each and every time the function is called.  That is a major waste of CPU cycles.  Suggest keeping that array, call `realloc()` if necessary, then the array only gets initialized once